# Is there anyway not to use optional for conditional assignment?

Tags: swift

I find myself in this situation a lot

```
func method() -> expensiveObj {    
var x: expensiveObj?    //this has to be optional or compiler complains not initialized

    if someCondition {
      x = expensiveObj() 
    } else P {
      x = expensiveObj()
    }

    return x // <---this is not allowed, need to unwrap with !
}
```

my function doesnt want to return optional. And I dont like using ! all the time, overriding the compiler. And also I know there x is not optional to begin with. It's either one value or another, never nil.

How do I overcome this?

Comment: It doesn’t need to be optional if you assign it a value on all paths.

Comment: Sorry maybe I shouldn't use string, but sometimes its other objects where it is expensive to init

Comment: You don’t have to give it an initial value. You just have to guarantee that it will have been given a value before it is read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, that's not true. This is legal, and (little-known fact) you can even use `let` instead of `var`:

```
func method() -> String {
    let x:String
    if someCondition {
        x = "1"
    } else {
        x = "2"
    }
    return x
}
```

The trick is that you *must* cover all possibilities in your `if`/`else` series. In other words, there must be no circumstances under which `x` goes uninitialized. If there are such circumstances, the compiler rightly stops you.

For example, this will *not* compile:

```
func method() -> String {
    let x:String
    if someCondition {
        x = "1"
    } else if anotherCondition {
        x = "2"
    }
    return x // error
}
```

And rightly so, because what if neither condition is true? You need a catch-all:

```
func method() -> String {
    let x:String
    if someCondition {
        x = "1"
    } else if anotherCondition {
        x = "2"
    } else {
        x = "3"
    }
    return x
}
```